# Why is the color information lost when image data is multiplied by and ellipse mask?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Trying to get an [Lomography Look](http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-make-digital-photos-look-like-lomo-photography/) I first tried to create a [Vignette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting) but the color information gets lost.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Mix-Node set to multiply must instead of a multiplying Math-Node be used to achieve the vignette effect.

[image]

Thats because a [*Math-Node's*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor) input is a scalar value and the color vector seems (I couldn't find a reference for that) to be converted to a single grayscale value. The [*Mix-Node*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Types/Color) is designed to process color data.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little information as to _why_ a mix node must be used, for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Math nodes only process a single value. While a mix node retains 3 channels of colour information. The math node effectively strips or contracts the channels down to one. Not sure if average or first in?

Comment: From a quick test it looks like it's an average.